# How to remove/prevent duplicate lines in a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been wracking my braining with this all day trying so many things on stack overflow and nothing is working, so apologies if this is something really simple and I'm missing it.

My situation is that my Python bot is grabbing a post ID from a post and putting it into a text file.

```
subreddit = reddit.subreddit('pythonforengineers')
# limiting the selection to the top 5 in hot
for submission in subreddit.new(limit=20):
    # re.findall is performing the filtering = removing all text but the found keys
    a = re.findall(steamKey15, submission.selftext, re.IGNORECASE)
    b = re.findall(steamKey25, submission.selftext, re.IGNORECASE)
    c = re.findall(steamKey17, submission.selftext, re.IGNORECASE)
    readPostIDFile()
    while submission.id not in steamKeyPostID:
        if a:
            #print(a)
            savePostID()
            saveSteamKey()
            removeDups()
        if b:
            #print(b)
            savePostID()
            saveSteamKey()
            removeDups()
        if c:
            #print(c)
            savePostID()
            saveSteamKey()
            removeDups()
        break
```

This is my looping logic. The 3 variables are the steamKey15/25/17, so I'm testing it on a post with all 3 formats and naturally its returning all 3, but its also writing the post id 3x to my text file.

Here is the logic for the post id save:

```
def savePostID():
    #print(submission.selftext)                
    #print(submission.id)
    # adds the id to the text file
    steamKeyPostID.append(submission.id)
    with open('steamKeyPostID.txt', 'a') as f:
        for post_id in steamKeyPostID:
            f.write(submission.id + '\n')
            if submission.id not in 'steamKeyPostID.txt':      
                print('Beep. Boop. Bot saving the keys of: ' + '"' + submission.title + '"'+ ' to ---> steamKeys.txt')
                break           
            else:
                print('No keys were found!')
                break
```

My goal is to either prevent multiple post IDs from reaching the text file, OR to perform a filtering on the text file to remove the duplicates(this would require writing back to the same text file). I'm not sure which would be easier, but I've been trying both all day and failing.

I have tried using OrderedDict and set() codes of varying types. I have also tried modifying my for/if loops and changing out what they are filtering for. I feel like this is so easy, but I'm just getting endless errors. I'm on Python 3.7.

I appreciate any help! I probably wont be looking into solution until tomorrow, I need a break.

Comment: `if submission.id not in 'steamKeyPostID.txt':` is actually checking if the post ID is in the phrase "steamKeyPostID.txt", e.g. "eamKey" is in "steamKeyPostID.txt", but "/comments/avb5u0/" (or whatever) is definitely not. You'll want to `read()` in the contents of your saved file, or switch to a lightweight database (like Python `shelve`) to get easy set membership checks.

Comment: Instead of just telling us about what you've tried, show us the code that you tried, and we can explain what you got wrong, and how to fix it.

Comment: @nelfin I've only been using Python for about a week now, so that solution might be right, but I have no idea what it is, or how to set it up/use it. Specifically regarding the `read()` not sure where to put that.

Comment: @abarnert I've pretty much tried every solution from googling 'Python remove duplicates from text file" on stack overflow. I'm not sure if I failed importing the code, or if it just didn't work. Apologies but I deleted the specific code in frustration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who stumbles upon this from googling. I found my solution by preventing duplicates from being added instead of removing them.

I used this code block:

```
# this is the logic block for ensuring duplicate posts are not read. 
with open('steamKeyPostID.txt', 'r') as f:
    #read the existing .txt file
    steamKeyPostID = f.read()
    #put it on a newline
    steamKeyPostID = steamKeyPostID.split('\n')
    #gets rid of empty elements in the .txt and saves it to a list(array kinda)
    steamKeyPostID = list(filter(None, steamKeyPostID))
```

What that should do is save all contents of the text file to a list. I then use a while statement to filter the list:

```
while submission.id not in steamKeyPostID:
```

submission.id is using Praw, the reddit API module.

This works perfectly for me when I rerun the program, it skips over all post ids in the text file.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already appending all `submission.id`s to `steamKeyPostID` in `savePostID()`, you can simply add a check of `if submission.id not in steamKeyPostID:` to avoid writing duplicates:

```
def savePostID():
    if submission.id not in steamKeyPostID:
        steamKeyPostID.append(submission.id)
        with open('steamKeyPostID.txt', 'a') as f:
            for post_id in steamKeyPostID:
                f.write(submission.id + '\n')
                ...
```

Comment: I think you meant `if submission.id not in steamKeyPostID`, otherwise you'd only add duplicates. Also, this only works for the duration that the bot is running: if it's restarted for any reason then duplicates will get written back in to the file.

Comment: @blhsing Thank you for the suggestion. This bot will be running from Windows Task Scheduler, so if what nelfin said is correct, then the duplicates would just be reposted every time its ran.